# Insert multiples values in the value of the checkbox

Tags: php, html, ajax, checkbox

What I want is to insert multiple values in the value of my checkbox and send it to my function myAlert(this) in only one String like "code_dateAdded_..."

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox"  onclick="myAlert(this)" name="code" id="code" value="'.$donnees['code'].'_'.$donnees['dateAdded'].'"/>'.$donnees['code'].'</td>';
```

the value should be like this value="355422_2015-07-30 03:00:16"

I tried to insert like that but when I do an echo on my value I only get the value of $donnees['code'] and not following values like the underscore and  $donnees['dateAdded']

The function :

```
function myAlert(str){
            if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("valSup").innerHTML = "";
            return;
            } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("valSup").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","myAlert.php?q="+str.value,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
```

And in myAlert.php I only do an echo of the parametre :

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);        
echo $q;
```

Is it possible to do like this and if not how can I do it

Thanks

Comment: what is your problem

Comment: what is you data type of the field in db for the same?

Comment: My problem is to insert multiples parametres in the value="" of my checkbox and get them in my function

Comment: check if 'dateAdded' and 'code' fields of $donnees array aren't empty.
Make `print_r($donnees)` and check result

Comment: they are not empty at least "code" because when I do an echo of this $donnees['code'].'_'.$donnees['dateAdded'] I only get $donnees['code']

Comment: the field in db for the same : code = bigint dateAdded = bigint

Answer (score 3):

You must try passing a string to the function in onclick, so it will be

```
onclick="myAlert(this.value)"
```

and accordingly, just treat the value passed as a string in your function.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","myAlert.php?q="+str,true);
```

As for converting your data, you should have:

```
$date = $donnees['dateAdded'];
$date = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$code = $strval($donnees['code']);

$inputVal = $code.'_'.$date;
```

to convert everything to a string.

Comment: It doesn't work, even the underscore is not taken into account

Comment: even in the table cell it doesn't display it as the content? did you try the code above?

Comment: yes I tried and yes it display in the table cell but not in the value. An echo of the value still gives me only $donnees['code']

Comment: @sarikaya, try now. Edited. Let me know please.

Comment: change your onclick to `onclick="alert(this.value)"` and let me know what you see.

Comment: I do this in my function already str.value I edited the post you can see my function. But I even tried what you said and I get the value 0.

Comment: you can't do this `if (str == "")`, because you're passing an object. If you'd wanna pass a string, you should have it as `onclick="myAlert(this.value)"` instead.

Comment: @sarikaya, you should try the new edit. Please let me know.

Comment: no it doesn't work. I think there is something related with the database. Code is a bigint and dateAdded a datetime and I have to convert them to string probably

Comment: Ah you should have said that earlier!! Please check the answer again, edited.

Comment: I get this error : Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\getTableBuffer.php on line 53

Comment: Doesn't work why is it that complicated I get this error : date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

Comment: then that means it's already a string, try to comment that line, and check it again. `//$date = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: It works but when I do an echo I have only the year lol, I should have this : 2015-07-30 03:00:16 but I have this :  2015

Comment: then you should look into adjusting your formatting and its conversion to string. I am glad it works! :)